# Filling model fields using both data from form and other sources

Tags: django

I got a model that represents user's financial account:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    currencies_list = [currency.alpha_3 for currency in pycountry.countries]
    currencies_tuples = ((currency, currency) for currency in currencies_list)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=currencies_tuples)
    initial_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    current_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to allow user to create a new account using following view:

```
def new_account(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            account = form.save(commit=False)
            account.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = AccountForm()
        return render(request, 'expenses/new_account.html', {'form': form})
```

and form:

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['name', 'currency', 'initial_balance']
```

I'm only letting user to fill three fields: `name`, `currency` and `initial_balance`. I want fields `user` and `current_balance` to be filled automatically: `user` by copying currently logged user ID and `current_balance` by copying value provided by user for `initial_balance` field.

May I kindly ask you to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if form.is_valid():
    account = form.save(commit=False)
    account.user = request.user
    account.current_balance = form.cleaned_data.get('initial_balance')
    account.save()
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!